# Simplification of products of KroneckerDelta[]

Tags: simplifying-expressions

What is the reason why the following expression does not simplify to `True`?

```
Assuming[
  i > 0 && j > 0 && k > 0 && Element[{i, j, k}, Integers],
  FullSimplify[
    KroneckerDelta[i, j] * KroneckerDelta[i, k] == KroneckerDelta[i, j, k]
  ]
]

(* KroneckerDelta[i, j] KroneckerDelta[i, k] == KroneckerDelta[i, j, k] *)
```

Is there a corner case where this equation is actually false? Does Mathematica simply not know about this identity? If the latter is the case, how could I define a rule for `FullSimplify` to simplify products like the one on the left hand side?

Comment: If you use [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) then you would probably prefer `KroneckerDelta[i, j] * KroneckerDelta[i, k]` to simplify to `KroneckerDelta[j,k]`, for example.  So it is likely easier to just allow the user to specify their desired behavior.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to "teach" `KroneckerDelta` about this:

```
Unprotect[KroneckerDelta];
KroneckerDelta /: (Times[KroneckerDelta[i_, j_], KroneckerDelta[k_, m_]] /; i == k) := 
      KroneckerDelta[i, j, m]
Protect[KroneckerDelta];
```

After the above, here is the new behavior:

```
KroneckerDelta[a, b] KroneckerDelta[c, d] (* this doesn't match *)
KroneckerDelta[a, b] KroneckerDelta[a, d] (* your use case *)

(* Out:
KroneckerDelta[a, b] KroneckerDelta[c, d]
KroneckerDelta[a, b, d]
*)
```

Comment: Thanks. That got me on the right track. I currently use `KroneckerDelta /: (Times[KroneckerDelta[i_, j__], KroneckerDelta[i_, k__]]) := KroneckerDelta[i, j, k]`, which is a little bit more general, I think.

Comment: @DavidZwicker Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Adding `PiecewiseExpand[]` forces the conversion of `KroneckerDelta[]` into `Piecewise[]` equivalents, which play nicer with simplification:

```
Assuming[i > 0 && j > 0 && k > 0 && {i, j, k} ∈ Integers, 
         KroneckerDelta[i, j] KroneckerDelta[i, k] == KroneckerDelta[i, j, k]
         // PiecewiseExpand // Simplify]
```

---

Another method consists of converting `KroneckerDelta[]` expressions into the equivalent Iverson brackets (i.e., `Boole[]`):

```
KroneckerDelta[i, j] KroneckerDelta[i, k] == KroneckerDelta[i, j, k] /.
k_KroneckerDelta :> Boole[Equal @@ k] // FullSimplify
```